# Fill a array with List data with one more element

Tags: java, list, arrays, copy

By a question that I made, I figured out that tho copy elements from one list to an array I just need to use the method **toArray()** for this.

But let's suppose I have a List with **n** objects. I want to copy then into a array sized **n+1** and add into the first position another object and in the other **n** positions the **n** data of the list.

This is the way I'm doing it for now, but I'm just wondering if there is a better way for do that:

```
    Object array[] = new Object[list.size() + 1];

    Object chk = new Object();

    array[0] = chk;

    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understood what you are trying to achieve with that, but if I understood the problem correctly, this is how I would do it:

```
    List<Object> elementList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Object additionalElement = new Object();
    Object array[] = null;

    //[Add code to populate the List]

    //Add the additional element
    elementList.add(0,additionalElement);

    array = elementList.toArray();
```

This would do the trick with the advantage of not iterating anything.

Comment: But would't this add method change the element located in the position 0?

Comment: This approach would change the list: It adds a new element at position 0, moving all other elements by one place (position 0 to position 1 etc.).

Comment: Thanks @Christian. I didn't know this add implementation shfted up the indices of the subsequent values.

Comment: The `set` method overwrites the element at the given index instead of inserting it.

Comment: I'm confused here - both the `code to populate the List` and the `toArray()` would have to iterate. This doesn't "have the advantage of not iterating anything" at all.

Comment: @corsiKa if you read marionmaiden's problem, the code to populate is out of scope. The solution above achieves what he is asking without any iterations (extra iterations in case the population code requires any), therefore the advantage.

Comment: @Chepech Even if that were the case (which it isn't) `toArray()` still iterates. To say it doesn't is like saying a mob boss saying to his captain "Shame if Joey Baretti had an accident" and claiming he didn't order a hit.

Comment: What I intend to say is, there is no iteration on the code on you write (Which is objectively true if you read the code), I was not accounting for implementations. You can edit the response if you think the claim is misrepresenting what really is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You could used a LinkedList and use offerFirst() and then toArray(), but I doubt it really matters.

Comment: Where is this offerFirst method from?

Comment: `offerFirst(E)` is a new funtion in Java 1.6 (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#offerFirst%28E%29) which adds a given element at the start of the list. It has the same effect on the list as `addFirst(E)` and `add(0, E)`.

Comment: It seems that offerFirst is only available in the LinkedLists. The other implementations of list interface doesn't have this method.

Answer (score 2):

use an iterator:

```
...

int i = 1;
for(Object item:list){
    array[i] = item;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: +1: Iteration is more efficient than the `get(i)` solution for some kinds of lists, like `LinkedList`. And this solution does not change the list, unlike some other answers given here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to avoid having to loop through the array and the list, I think you're out of luck.  Java doesn't provide a way to do a mass copy except for ones that just use a API call that does the looping through the collection behind the scenes, hidden from view.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without your loop would be:

```
Object array[] = new Object[list.size() + 1];
Object oldValues[] = list.toArray();

Object chk = new Object();
array[0] = chk;
System.arrayCopy(oldValues, 0, array, 1, oldValues.length);
```

`System.arrayCopy` is a bit faster than looping (not too much, but faster nevertheless), although the performance boost would probably be mitigated by the `toArray`, depending on the implementation of your List.

All in all, what you have is a decent approach as long as `List.get(int)` is an acceptable cost. (If it's O(n), you'll end up with O(n^2) for your operation, which is suboptimal when Frank's solution is O(n).)

Comment: That's not the ONLY way, please see above

Comment: @Chepech Okay so it's been ten years BUT - the answer above uses `add` which uses `grow` internally, which uses `Arrays.copyOf` which uses...... drumroll.... `System.arrayCopy` - so I mean, yeah, it kind of is the only way. <3